# call a oracle procedure from inside a sql block

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If I have a .sql file with this :

```
begin
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('schema',table');
end;
/
```

Should I need to use :

```
call 'exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('schema',table')';
```

I cannot test it out because of system problems so i am posting my query here.

Comment: Is dbms_stats.gather_table_stats a function or a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, both are flawed - exec is used in SQL/Plus without a begin/end block, and call is definitely not PL/SQL; you'd also probably have to escape the single quotes inside your call statement.
You can just use

```
begin
 dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('ALERTS_OWNER','ASYNC_PROCESSING_REQUEST_T');
end;
```